# Is it possible to get Ashara to max Affection as a female Inquisitor?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm an Inquisitor and I recently got Ashara as a companion. I also recently maxed out Affection on Khem Val, so I was thinking about trying to max out Ashara as well. Looking at her [Torhead entry](http://www.torhead.com/npc/hAbptyD/ashara-zavros), though, it seems like she doesn't really like *any* companion gifts if you have a female Inquisitor.

Are there enough dialogue options for gaining Affection with Ashara over the rest of the story to get her to maximum Affection without completely bankrupting myself getting her gifts?

Comment: I got all of my sorcerer companions up to 100%. I don't think I bankrupted myself although I did do a lot of crew missions for gifts. I also had purchased three legacy perk levels of the improved companion conversation gain and three of the improved gift gain.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are not enough conversation options.  I've just started maxing her myself.  I don't think four types of gifts are particularly few, though.

However, you might be able to raise her affection through repeatable quests.  Several of the Belsavis dailies have choices that affect companion affection, for example.  But it will be slow!